# Bypass expensive initialisation when called internally

Tags: python, class

Let's say I have a class with an init function that does many expensive checks on the input data, before storing it as an attribute:

```py
def expensive_function_to_verify_data_is_ok(data) -> bool:
    (...)

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, data):
        if not expensive_function_to_verify_data_is_ok(data):
            raise ValueError("Your data cannot be used to create a MyClass object!")
        self._data = data
    
    ...
```

Now, objects are sometimes instantiated by an internal process, in which case the checks are not necessary, because I can be sure the data is OK.

**Is there a way to change the class definition, to allow for this? I.e., to bypass the checks in this case?**

The signature of the `__init__` method should ideally remain unchanged.

I thought about adding a class method for internal calls, but that will eventually still need to call `__init__()`, and therefore does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Add an optional argument that indicates whether you've already done the checks.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, data, checked=False):
        if not checked and not expensive_function_to_verify_data_is_ok(data):
            raise ValueError("Your data cannot be used to create a MyClass object!")
        self._data = data
```

Then the internal users can use `MyClass(somedata, checked=True)`

Another option is to assign `_data` using a separate method from `__init__()`.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._data = None

    @property
    def data(self):
        return self._data

    @data.setter
    def  data(self, data):
        if not expensive_function_to_verify_data_is_ok(data):
            raise ValueError("Your data cannot be used to create a MyClass object!")
        self._data = data
```

This means that normal callers will have to do:

```
mc = MyClass()
mc.data = new_value
```

Internal callers can do

```
mc = MyClass()
mc._data = new_value
```

Here's another way. Rename the class to `MyClass_internal`, and define `MyClass()` as an ordinary function. This function performs the data validation before calling `MyClass_internal()` to create the instance. Internal code can call `MyClass_internal()` directly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought about that as well, but I would rather not have an additional parameter in the initialisation, if it can be avoided. Even if I add an underscore (`_checked`), it still clutters up the signature.

Comment: I've added another alternative of setting `_data` via a property instead of in the `__init__()` method, and bypassing the property for internal users.

Comment: Concerning your update: this too changes the signature. 

I have looked at `pandas`, [it seems like they use your initial method](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/core/series.py?plain=1#L371). I suppose, if it's good enough for pandas, it's good enough for me ;) But I'll still wait and see if there are other solutions people come up with.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do it like you want. There's no reasonable way to bypass the `__init__()` method.

Comment: I added another method where you rename the class.